# Passing a list of class instances to multiprocessing.Pool and parallelize the running of method function of each class objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a list of class instances. Each of this class objects have a method function that I want to run and I want to parallelize across the class instances since there's a lot of them. For example, I have this class object:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def register(self):
        self.registered = True
```

Now I defined a list of class instances of `Person()`

```
persons = [Person(i) for i in ["Bernard", "Enrik", "Joseph"]]
```

I want to parallelize the running of `Person.register()` method function across the values in persons. Using multiprocessing.Pool, here's what I did. Since you can't pickle method function, I wrap it in another function.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def reg(person):
    person.register()
pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()//2)
res = list(pool.map(reg, persons))
```

The code runs without error by the way, so now I am expecting that every Person instance in the list will have an attribute `registered` set to `True` but when I check each class instance, it doesn't contain attribute `registered`. For example, checking if `registered` is an attribute of persons[0],

```
hasattr(persons[0], "registered")
>>> False
```

Why is this so? How can I solve this?

Comment: You have got the map. That is a good start. Now collect it in a container and be happy. `list(pool.map(reg, persons))` would be my first try as `list(map(reg, persons))` will set the attribute for all your `Person`s ;)

Comment: Do you mean I should put a return statement in `Person.register()` and given the `list(pool.map(reg, persons))`, I should run another function that would explicitly assign the attribute `registered` to each class object?

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar problem here: [Python multiprocessing with pathos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059764/python-multiprocessing-with-pathos). The reason why the Person class instance doesn't have attribute `registered` is that in the multiprocessing, the Pool creates processes that are just copies of the class instances in the list, thus, to solve this, in wrapper function `reg()` return the class instances, that is,

```
def reg(person):
    person.register()
    return person
pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()//2)
persons = list(pool.map(reg, persons))
```

Comment: I am doing this with my own class, method and wrapper function, but i get something that would be for this code as follows: `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle reg: attribute lookup reg on __main__ failed`, anyone know why?

Comment: @someoneb100, did you make sure that wrapper reg() function is outside the class?

Comment: yes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795810/applying-a-method-in-a-list-of-class-objects-using-multiprocessing here is my problem